# How to delete more lines in between lines you like python?

Tags: python, file, pandas, lines

I have a weird file format

```
###########################################################
# Name of file#
# stuff[hh:mm:ss:ms] stuff[num] stuff[num] stuff[] stuff[]#
###########################################################
00:00:00.000 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
00:00:00.001 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
00:00:00.002 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
00:00:00.003 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
00:00:00.004 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
00:00:00.005 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
00:00:00.006 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
00:00:00.007 -1000 -1000 0.000001 20
```

the problem is I need only info every 2 sec. Which means i need to edit out 1999 lines in between.(the space is actually /t) What is the best way of doing that. I would also like to have the numbers saved as numbers not strings.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="\t",
names=("time", "num1", "num2", "num3", "num4"), skiprows=4)
df["abs_time"] = df.index * 1e-3
```

I had to define time differently i already have the code for that i just need to save it properly.

```
def get_sec(time_str):
m, s, ss = time_str.split(':')
return int(m) * 60 + int(s) + 0.01*int(ss)
```

Any help well appreciated.

Comment: Is your file that regular on timming ?

Comment: Yeah every millisecond

Comment: Are there string in your first column ?

Comment: the first 4 lines are a header that doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `skiprows` parameter to get odd rows (or even). From the documentation:

> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row
>   indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
>   otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x in [0, 2].

Here you have an example csv:

```
#
#
#
#
A,B
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
```

Then you can:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=lambda x: True if x < 4 or x%2 == 1 else False)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  2  2
1  4  4
```

As you can see, you can read odd or even lines and thus getting only rows every 2 seconds. Notice though, this assumes:

1. You are using latest pandas version 0.20.2
2. Your data is consecutive, i.e. one row per second

Comment: One row every millisecond

Comment: @user8230258 Then you can change `x%2==1` for `x % 2000 == 1`. Hope helps :)

Comment: @user8230258 You mean having a data frame and writing it to a file skipping certain rows?

Comment: Yes. I have a bunch of files that have "too much information".

Comment: @user8230258 But you have data frames, not files. There's something I'm missing. If you didn't post your question correctly, please edit it. If this is another question, then post another question. Answering in the comments is difficult

Comment: At the top i said i have a weird file format that was an extraction out of the files i am working with. (sorry if i was a bit unclear first time posting)

Comment: @user8230258 But we already answered how to read this weird file. Now you are asking how to *write* a file skipping rows, am I right?

Comment: Oh right. My bad. I am trying to have it also write down so its easier to handle later on.

Comment: @user8230258 Ok, no problem. Once you read it skipping lines, use `pandas.to_csv` method to write a data frame to a `csv` file format.

Comment: @user8230258 Yes, it was. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you need data for every 2 seconds, it will indicate you need to have second which is even and ending with "000"(you could choose odd seconds as well) assuming you have no missing data

```
def is_select(time_str):
    return str.endswith(time_str, ".000") and int(time_str[6:8])%2
df['even_seconds'] = pd.apply(lambda x: is_select(x["time"]), axis=1)
select_data = df[df.even_seconds==True]
```

`x["time"][6:8]`will give you seconds information (you could adjust the index yourself).

Of course, you could modify lambda function for other data selections.

Answer (score 0):

You cumsum the milisecond and check if they are modulo 2000, assuming you have strings in your first column.

```
vector_bool = df[df.columns[0]].apply(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1]).astype(int).cumsum().apply( lambda x: x%2000 == 0 )
```

Then take only the row wich are true.

```
df_clean = df[vector_bool]
```